# Lambda output is going to Logs rather than displaying in reponse?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to merge two JSON objects which I rendered from different services into one. I am getting desired output but the output is going into logs rather than showing in Response.

Updated Lambda code using Async/Await

```
       const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
exports.handler =async(event, context, callback)=> {
const S3 = new AWS.S3({region: "ap-south-1",apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});
const cloudwatch = new AWS.CloudWatch({region: "ap-south-1",apiVersion: '2010-08-01'});
const params= {};
var itemsProcessed = 0;
try {
    const instancesData = await S3.listBuckets(params).promise();
    var size = Object.keys(instancesData.Buckets).length;
    var MName = [];
//   instancesData.Buckets.forEach(function(x){
//       BName.push(x.Name);
//   });
   for (let i = 0; i < size;i++) {
       var Json1 = instancesData.Buckets[i];
       var BuckName = instancesData.Buckets[i].Name;
    //   itemsProcessed++;
       var params1 = {
        EndTime: 1536128999, /* required */
        MetricDataQueries: [ /* required */
            {
                Id: 'm17', /* required */
                MetricStat: {
                  Metric: { /* required */
                    Dimensions: [
                    //   {
                    //     Name: 'BucketName', /* required */
                    //     Value: x /* required */
                    //   },
                      {
                        Name: 'BucketName', /* required */
                        Value: BuckName /* required */
                      },
                      {
                        Name: 'StorageType', /* required */
                        Value: 'StandardStorage' /* required */
                      }
                      /* more items */
                    ],
                    MetricName: 'BucketSizeBytes',
                    Namespace: 'AWS/S3'
                  },
                  Period: 86400, /* required */
                  Stat: 'Sum', /* required */
                  Unit: 'Bytes'
                },
                ReturnData: true
              },
              /* more items */
            ],
            StartTime: 1536085800, /* required */
          };
          var Json2 = await cloudwatch.getMetricData(params1).promise();
          var obj = Object.assign(Json1, Json2);
           MName.push(obj);
   }
   callback(null,MName); 
 }
catch (err) {
        callback(err.message);
    }    

};
```

This is the one worked for me . It will store all the combined json in an array and i will use that array in my callback function.

Any help is appreciated 
Thanks

Comment: This is a standard async JavaScript problem. You're going to have to learn how to use Promises or async/await so that your Lambda function does not complete until all of its S3 and CloudWatch calls have completed. It's worth reading https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/node-js-8-10-runtime-now-available-in-aws-lambda/ and https://irvinlim.com/blog/async-await-on-aws-lambda/

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "response section" vs "logs section". These things don't exist. There are logs, and there is a result. When you call console.log(), a log appears in CloudWatch Logs. When your Lambda function completes, it can/should yield a result. I don't know what you want that result to be, but right now it's the string "success", and it's potentially happening at the wrong time (before all of the async AWS SDK calls have completed).

Comment: If you simply want your buckets & their merged metrics logged to CloudWatch Logs then continue to use console.log(). If you actually want to return that data as the result of the Lambda function, then accumulate those objects in an array, and make that the result of the Lambda function. Either way, you need to resolve the current problem where you are making the result callback before all of the SDK calls are complete. Please read the earlier links.

Comment: Hi, the solution you have right now using setTimeout() is not ideal. You're guessing how long the code will take to complete and that's fragile, and unnecessary. It will either cost you more than necessary (if processing finishes early) or it will fail to provide the correct results (if processing finishes too late). I will add a more reliable solution as an answer. It's important that you learn more about async JavaScript.

Comment: **Moderator Note**: Please don't vandalize your posts. Once you post a question, they
  belong to the site and its users. Even if it is no longer useful to
  you, it might still be  beneficial to someone in the future. If there
  is any confidential information revealed in your post, please edit it
  out with dummy data, and flag for the history to be redacted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AWS SDK functions are asynchronous, as a general rule, so it's important to understand how to program asynchronous JavaScript using Promises and using async/await.

Here's one way to do it that's a little more linear and hopefully a little easier to follow.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const _ = require('lodash');

const S3 = new AWS.S3({
  region: 'ap-south-1',
  apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
});

const cloudwatch = new AWS.CloudWatch({
  region: 'ap-south-1',
  apiVersion: '2010-08-01',
});

const metrics = async (bucketName) => {
  const params = {
    EndTime: 1536128999,
    MetricDataQueries: [{
      Id: 'm17',
      MetricStat: {
        Metric: {
          Dimensions: [
            {
              Name: 'BucketName',
              Value: bucketName,
            },
            {
              Name: 'StorageType',
              Value: 'StandardStorage',
            },
          ],
          MetricName: 'BucketSizeBytes',
          Namespace: 'AWS/S3',
        },
        Period: 86400,
        Stat: 'Sum',
        Unit: 'Bytes',
      },
      ReturnData: true,
    }],
    StartTime: 1536085800,
  };

  return cloudwatch.getMetricData(params).promise();
};

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  try {
    // List all bucket data
    const bucketData = await S3.listBuckets({}).promise();

    // Use map to transform bucket data to just the bucket names
    const bucketNames = _.map(bucketData.Buckets, bucket => bucket.Name);

    // Get metrics for each bucket by name
    const bucketMetrics = await Promise.all(_.map(bucketNames, bucket => metrics(bucket)));

    // Use map to transform bucket metrics to just the bucket sizes
    const bucketSizes = bucketMetrics.map(m => m.MetricDataResults[0].Values[0] || 0);

    // Use zipWith to combine the bucket names and corresponding bucket sizes
    return _.zipWith(bucketNames, bucketSizes, (bn, bs) => ({ bucket: bn, size: bs }));
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
    throw err;
  }
};
```

The result of this code looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "bucket": "mybucket-of-images",
    "size": 1209721781
  },
  {
    "bucket": "backup-project",
    "size": 2048
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks @jarmod for providing me the solution .Anyway I updated the one which worked for me without the `setimeout`. Let me your suggestions.

Comment: `bucketMetrics` would be in the order of `bucketNames` that passed, at all times?

Comment: Good question. Yes, the metrics for the Nth bucket name will be the Nth item in the bucketMetrics list because the items in the list of resolved values from Promise.all() corresponds to the order that the original promises were presented.

Comment: Thanks @jarmod because i am merging names with metrics that why i wanted to make sure. If they are not then i am gone :)